Identifying Peaks (Local Maxima) and Troughs (Local Minima) in Data and Labeling them
I have data that resembles this:
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed(901)
rand_list= []
for i in range(20):
    x = random.randint(480,600)
    rand_list.append(x/10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'INDEX':rand_list})
df['INDEX_DIFF'] = df.INDEX.diff()
df

    INDEX   INDEX_DIFF
0   53.5    NaN
1   56.4    2.9
2   51.7    -4.7
3   49.4    -2.3
4   55.4    6.0
5   49.9    -5.5
6   52.9    3.0
7   57.7    4.8
8   54.2    -3.5
9   51.4    -2.8
10  57.1    5.7
11  56.7    -0.4
12  58.5    1.8
13  52.1    -6.4
14  57.6    5.5
15  56.1    -1.5
16  54.2    -1.9
17  52.9    -1.3
18  56.6    3.7
19  53.2    -3.4

I want to identify instances where the INDEX value crosses 50 from below and keeps growing while above 50. The first instance when INDEX_DIFF shows -ve indicates that the INDEX has peaked above 50.
For instance, the 6th value 49.9 crosses 50 and continues to grow (52.9, 57.7) before peaking at 57.7 and dropping to 54.2 in the next instance. The INDEX_DIFF gives the first negative value since crossing 50 from below.
How to check this condition and label this as a Peak in a new column in the pandas dataframe?
I have tried to use Last occurrence of a condition but don't know how to check this elaborate condition.

Could you provide the exact expected output for completeness?

The X would appear next to the first -ve value. We would know the INDEX has peaked only after the drop in the next instance. That would be the only change.

Do you want to find only local maxima after a dip below 50? I.e, does value 1 count? Also, do you want every local maxima between a pair of <50 values, or just the largest one?

@SimonLundberg This is not an exact science.  I just need the logic and sample code. I can work with it to figure out how to use it. mozway 's graphs below are spot on in describing the problem. I am also looking for the local minima that occurs below 50 with similar and inverted conditions.

You could use masks to identify the chunks above 50 (and that started below 50), then get the groupby.idxmax:
m1 = df['INDEX'].shift().lt(50)
m2 = df['INDEX'].gt(50)

group = (m1 & m2).cumsum()

maxima = df[group>0].groupby(group)['INDEX'].idxmax().tolist()
# [4, 12]

df.loc[maxima, 'peak'] = 'X'

Output:
    INDEX  INDEX_DIFF peak
0    53.5         NaN  NaN
1    56.4         2.9  NaN
2    51.7        -4.7  NaN
3    49.4        -2.3  NaN
4    55.4         6.0    X
5    49.9        -5.5  NaN
6    52.9         3.0  NaN
7    57.7         4.8  NaN
8    54.2        -3.5  NaN
9    51.4        -2.8  NaN
10   57.1         5.7  NaN
11   56.7        -0.4  NaN
12   58.5         1.8    X
13   52.1        -6.4  NaN
14   57.6         5.5  NaN
15   56.1        -1.5  NaN
16   54.2        -1.9  NaN
17   52.9        -1.3  NaN
18   56.6         3.7  NaN
19   53.2        -3.4  NaN

If you want all peaks (not just the largest one):
m1 = df['INDEX'].shift().lt(50)
m2 = df['INDEX'].gt(50)
m3 = (m1 & m2).cummax()

peak = df['INDEX'].diff().gt(0) & df['INDEX'].diff(-1).gt(0)

df['peak'] = np.where(m3 & peak, 'X', '')

Output:
    INDEX  INDEX_DIFF peak
0    53.5         NaN     
1    56.4         2.9     
2    51.7        -4.7     
3    49.4        -2.3     
4    55.4         6.0    X
5    49.9        -5.5     
6    52.9         3.0     
7    57.7         4.8    X
8    54.2        -3.5     
9    51.4        -2.8     
10   57.1         5.7    X
11   56.7        -0.4     
12   58.5         1.8    X
13   52.1        -6.4     
14   57.6         5.5    X
15   56.1        -1.5     
16   54.2        -1.9     
17   52.9        -1.3     
18   56.6         3.7    X
19   53.2        -3.4     

Graph approach 1:

Graph approach 2:


You can identify local maxima and minima with following code
df['MIN'] = df['INDEX'][(df['INDEX'].shift(1) > df['INDEX']) & (df['INDEX'].shift(-1) > df['INDEX'])]
df['MAX'] = df['INDEX'][(df['INDEX'].shift(1) < df['INDEX']) & (df['INDEX'].shift(-1) < df['INDEX'])]

df.loc[pd.notna(df["MIN"]), "EXTREMA"] = "trough"
df.loc[pd.notna(df["MAX"]), "EXTREMA"] = "peak"

The result is:



""
INDEX
INDEX_DIFF
MIN
MAX
EXTREMA




0
53.5
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN


1
56.4
2.9
NaN
56.4
peak


2
51.7
-4.7
NaN
NaN
NaN


3
49.4
-2.3
49.4
NaN
trough


4
55.4
6.0
NaN
55.4
peak


5
49.9
-5.5
49.9
NaN
trough


6
52.9
3.0
NaN
NaN
NaN


7
57.7
4.8
NaN
57.7
peak


8
54.2
-3.5
NaN
NaN
NaN


9
51.4
-2.8
51.4
NaN
trough


10
57.1
5.7
NaN
57.1
peak


11
56.7
-0.4
56.7
NaN
trough


12
58.5
1.8
NaN
58.5
peak


13
52.1
-6.4
52.1
NaN
trough


14
57.6
5.5
NaN
57.6
peak


15
56.1
-1.5
NaN
NaN
NaN


16
54.2
-1.9
NaN
NaN
NaN


17
52.9
-1.3
52.9
NaN
trough


18
56.6
3.7
NaN
56.6
peak


19
53.2
-3.4
NaN
NaN
NaN




Your answer does not start marking peaks only after the data has dipped below 50 as requested nor does it confirm that the peaks are only above 50 (also requested)
